# AspectJ Pointcut call on JAX-RS annotated Interface method

Tags: java, interface, jax-rs, aspectj, pointcuts

I'm trying to intercept a method of an interface annoted with a JAX-RS @POST. My Pointcut works for all non-interface methods and if the @POST-Annotation is directly at the called method.

The interface method to intercept:

```
@POST
Response postToConnector(@Context CallContext callContext, String contentStream) throws Exception;
```

The Pointcut to match the method:

```
@Pointcut("call(@(javax.ws.rs.DELETE || javax.ws.rs.GET || javax.ws.rs.HEAD || javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS || "
    + "javax.ws.rs.POST || javax.ws.rs.PUT) public * org.myapp..webapi..*(..))")
public void anyPublicWebApiPointcut()
{
...
}
```

The interface is inside a package com.myapp.social.webapi.v1 and even if I change the method to public AspectJ will not intercept the call.

Is there anything to change within my Pointcut? How can I make this working?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What a `call()` pointcut does is, as the name implies, intercept calls to a certain method/constructor. In order for this to work, the caller (i.e. the piece of code where the call is located) must be under your control, i.e. it must have been woven. So if e.g. you have woven the `org.myapp..webapi..*` classes and the call has also been issued from there, it should work. That it does not work makes me assume that the POST calls come from somewhere outside the woven code, e.g. the JRE or a 3rd party library.

So if `org.myapp..webapi..*` is under your control, i.e. you can weave aspect code into it, you should use an `execution()` pointcut. In contrast to `call()` it is woven into the callee, i.e. into the code where the method is defined, not into the many places where it is called. This way you can intercept all method executions, regardless if they come from within your application or 3rd party or JRE code. It will even work for method executions triggered by reflection.

`call()` and `execution()` have fundamentally different semantics which pay off to learn and understand. As a rule of thumb, you should try to use `execution()` whenever possible, i.e. whenever the callee is weavable for you. `call()` is just your fall-back if you cannot weave into the callee and must use the caller. `call()` can also make sense if for some reason you need to make any decisions based on the joinpoint context, e.g. in an `around()` advice which decides to call or not to call the original method based on some condition.